# Why I can't fill this form using Python "requests" library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to fill a sign-in form using `requests` library in Python. As you see below, the name of fields are `username` and `password` :
[image]

So I wrote the below script:

```
session = requests.session()
p = session.post("http://192.168.94.1/SubSystem/Portal/Index1/Login/Login2.aspx", {'username':'myUsername','password':'myPassword'})
print 'headers', p.headers
print 'cookies', requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)
print 'html',  p.text
```

The problem is, when I run that, it returns the Sign-in page again! What's wrong with my program?

**Update :**

I also tried to send the parameters as data, but nothing changed. i.e the below code returns the same output also :

```
payload = {'username': 'myUsername', 'password': 'myPassword'}
r = requests.post("http://192.168.94.1/SubSystem/Portal/Index1/Login/Login2.aspx", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

**Update2 :**

I catch the packets using *Burp Suit* to see the difference :

This it the packet that my browser sends :

```
POST /SubSystem/Portal/Index1/Login/Login2.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.94.1
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 134
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://192.168.94.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://192.168.94.1/SubSystem/Portal/Index1/Login/Login2.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=nntwluu5uhrldzuymsv333uc; CURRENT_LANGUAGE_2=fa

__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTY5ODAzNzY1MmRkpL4TXtJfODqn0yxypIJaOzkl4YUWynT8urN%2BYYXM%2FnY%3D&Command=LOGIN&username=myUsername&password=myPassword
```

And this it the packet that the second Python script sends :

```
POST /SubSystem/Portal/Index1/Login/Login2.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.94.1
Content-Length: 31
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.4.3 CPython/2.7.0 Windows/7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=myUsername&password=myPassword
```

Comment: try putting parameters as `data` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: @EsseTi Tried, nothing changed. Same output.

Comment: In the `.post` you've done `payload = {'username': 'myUsername', 'passowrd': 'myPassword'}` - notice the typo'd `passowrd`?

Comment: @JonClements I correct it.Nothing changed. Thanks

Comment: @Jean okay... but now you're not using the `session` object...

Comment: @JonClements Please take a look at _Update2_, I think it can help you to help me! :)

Comment: @Jean Not sure, but try: `session = requests.session()` then just do a get for the the page `r = requests.get(url)`, then do your `r = session.post(url, data=payload)` and see if that's sufficient (that way - any cookies present from the get will be available for the post to trigger the login - probably the `ASP.NET_SessionId=nntwluu5uhrldzuymsv333uc` is required)

Comment: @JonClements I tried the session object also, nothing changed again!

Comment: @JonClements What shall I do now? I sniffed the connection with Brup Suite again. For the session object also it doesn't send the `ASP.NET_SessionId`. I didn't understand your comment clearly. Does that mean I must send `ASP.NET_SessionId` with my Python script also? if so, how?

Comment: @Jean well, one difference is that the browser post is sending a hidden field... so you need a `{'Command': 'LOGIN'}` added to your `payload` (look at the bottom line of your updated edit to see the difference in the fields being sent...)

Comment: and (probably, not sure) `button=submit` or something like that.  can you change the form action to an url where you can see the posted data in plain text?

Comment: @JonClements Yes! you are right. it works now. May I ask you to add it as an answer and let me check it? Moreover, what about the pictures in the page? When I save this output as a _.html_ file, I can't see the images. Is there any way to see the complete page?

Comment: @EsseTi The problem solve using adding 'Command' to the data. But may I ask you to explain how I can do that? (changing the form action to an url ...)?

Comment: @Jean answer's up - please pay note to the 2nd paragraph as well... You may wish to consider asking a new Q as to how to work out your most recent comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you firstly need to send a POST request, but from your recent update, that POST also expects some cookies available - there's also a hidden field called "Command" that needs to be sent with the value "LOGIN", so.

```
import requests

URL = "http://192.168.94.1/SubSystem/Portal/Index1/Login/Login2.aspx"

# Set up session object so we can store cookies across requests
session = requests.session()
# GET the page to get any initial cookies required for the POST
r = session.get(URL)
# POST to the login form (making sure to add "Command")
r = session.post(URL, data={'Command': 'LOGIN', 'username': 'x', 'password': 'y'})
```

As to why you don't get images when you save the page is that when a browser loads a page, it sees links to resources/stylesheets/images and issues further requests to access them - all `requests` does is load the "text" of the page as it were. There's ways of achieving this, but that's out of scope as an answer to the core question here.

---

As per the comment regarding *Can I do multiple logins using these session objects?* - here's one way of doing it...

```
# List of users and passwords
USERS = {
    'rod': 'password1',
    'jane': 'password2',
    'freddy': 'password3'
}
# Initial name->initial session with cookies
sessions = {name:requests.session().get(URL) for name in USERS}
# Login users
sessions.update(
    (name, session.post(URL, data={'Command': 'LOGIN', 'username': name, 'password': USERS[name]})) 
    for name, session in sessions.items()
)
# Now do something with users
r1 = sessions['rod'].get('http://something.com')
r2 = sessions['freddy'].get('http://something.com', params={'foo': 'bar'})
# etc...
```

Comment: Can I do multiple logins using these session objects? I mean is there any way to login with two or more username and password pairs simultaneously with a python process(program)?(Probably by specifying different cookies per posts?) Does this library any capability like this? Normally it is not possible in browsers.

Comment: @Jean you create N session objects (the equiv. of opening N many browsers in incognito/private mode)

Comment: @Jean given an (untested) example of that that I think you'll find easy enough to extend upon

Comment: Oh, yes! really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score -1):

Supporting  @EsseTi's answer,Use data=Payload method to get them. .

```
import requests
payload = {'id_login': 'UserName', 'id_password': 'Password'}
url = #Your URL
something = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```